# Using python to parse through text file with delimiter

Tags: python, parsing

I need to parse through a text file that looks like:

```
"id"$"date"$"text"

  10001$2016-01-11$"[start]
  this is some text
  [stop]
  "
  10002$2014-03-12$"[start]
  this is some more text
  [stop]
  "
```

with Python into a library and have those three different elements (id, date, and text) as the keys.

I'm not sure how to use the delimiter to split up those elements and how to use that first row as the keys for all elements in my list.

Could something like this work even to just print it:

```
infile = open('filename.txt', 'r')
for line in infile:
    if "????" in line:
        print(line, next(infile))
```

If I try:

```
infile = open('filename.txt', 'r')
   for line in infile:
    if '"text"' in line:
            print(next(infile))
```

it only prints the first line.

It would ideally look like:

```
[{'id':'10001', 'date':'2016-01-11', 'text':'this is some text'},{'id':'10002', 'date':'2014-03-12', 'text':'this is some more text'}]
```

Comment: What kind of trouble? Show us the code you used.

Comment: I think would be best if you post the file itself.

Comment: A Python `list` does not have named "keys". What's the desired format of the result data structure, as a Python type?

Comment: Looks like you want to use a " as a delimiter. It also looks like you don't want to read the file line by line since what you are trying to capture has newlines in it. You might want to look at the csv library and change the delimiter from , to $. There is are also quote settings.

Comment: line.split('$') will return a list of tokens splitted by the $ symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
with open(path,'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='$')
    res = [ {'id':line[0],'date':line[1],'text':line[2]} for line in reader ]
    res = res[1:]
```

Comment: `res[0]` comes back with `{'date': 'date', 'text': 'text', 'id': 'id'}` but everything after that works

Comment: @nquestion you can remove the first element

Comment: that one skips `{'id':'10001', 'date':'2016-01-11', 'text':'this is some text'}` and jumps to the second one. But if I take out `res = res[1:]` it doesn't.

Comment: @nquestion yes res= res[1:] and next() do the same thing. I think someone change my code. you can have either or those.

Comment: @nquestion please accept answer, if you like. Thank you

Comment: I want to grab a specific item within the text field. I tried this `for item in res:
     if "after this:" in item['text']:
             m=re.search('grab (..)',line)
     print m` but am getting `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer` any ideas?

Comment: @nquestion if you want to use regex to find item in string, try to test your pattern first http://regexr.com/

Comment: @nquestion or you can ask a new question with fully description.

Comment: done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651299/access-pieces-of-text-within-python-object

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's builtin [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library to parse the file.

```
import csv


class Parser(object):
    START_TEXT = "[start]"
    END_TEXT = "[stop]"

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename


    def parse_file(self):
        elements = []

        with open(self.filename, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='$')
            first_row = next(reader)

            key0 = first_row[0]
            key1 = first_row[1]
            key2 = first_row[2]

            for row in reader:
                elements.append({
                    key0: row[0],
                    key1: row[1],
                    key2: self.parse_text(row[2]),
                })

        return elements

    @classmethod
    def parse_text(cls, text):
        start_idx = text.index(cls.START_TEXT)
        end_idx = text.index(cls.END_TEXT)

        new_txt = text[start_idx + len(cls.START_TEXT):][:end_idx - len(cls.END_TEXT) - 1]

        return new_txt.lstrip('\n').rstrip('\n')


p = Parser("infile.txt")
elements = p.parse_file()

print elements
```

Outputs:

```
[{'date': '2016-01-11', 'text': 'this is some text', 'id': '10001'}, {'date': '2014-03-12', 'text': 'this is some more text', 'id': '10002'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('f.txt') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp, delimiter="$")
    data = list(reader)

for row in data:
    row.update({
        k:v.replace('[start]','').replace('[stop]','').replace('\n','')
        for k,v in row.items()})

print data
```