# Access pieces of text within Python object

Tags: python, parsing

I have an object that looks like
`block = [{'id':'10001', 'date':'2016-01-11', 'text':'this is some text. grab 40'},{'id':'10002', 'date':'2014-03-12', 'text':'this is some more text. grab 60'}]`

I would like to grab the item within `text` and reformat my object so it looks like:
`block = [{'id':'10001', 'date':'2016-01-11', 'text':'this is some text. grab 40', 'grabbed': '40'},{'id':'10002', 'date':'2014-03-12', 'text':'this is some more text. grab 60', 'grabbed': '60'}]`

I tried

```
for item in block:
 if "grab" in item['text']:
         m=re.search('grab (..)',line)
 print m
```

but got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string) TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi looks like the input to your regex is off:

```
m=re.search('grab (..)',line)
```

Where is the "line" coming from? Is that a string? Don't you want to search over "item['text']"?
Also note that "re.search" will not return matches; use e.g. re.findall().

Comment: Fixed, thanks. If the length of the item I am trying to grab varies and can be more than two characters so that saying `grab (..)` wouldn't always work... how could I accommodate that?

Comment: So if you are trying to capture more than two items, you can modify your regex like so:
(.*)  --> matches zero or none characters
(.+) --> matches one or more characters
(.{x}) --> matches x instances of characters.
If you google "regex cheat sheet", you will find helpful guides to the regex syntax.

Answer (score 1):

**No need for regex**. You can do as below

```
for b in block:
    b["grabbed"] = b["text"].rstrip().rsplit(" ",1)[-1]

In [205]: block
Out[205]:
[{'date': '2016-01-11',
  'grabbed': '40',
  'id': '10001',
  'text': 'this is some text. grab 40'},
 {'date': '2014-03-12',
  'grabbed': '60',
  'id': '10002',
  'text': 'this is some more text. grab 60'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

assume there is only 2 digits after grab and only one 'grab xx' in one string

```
for item in block:
 if "grab it" in item['text']:
        m = re.findall('grab \d{2}',item['text'])[0]
 print m
```

or assume after grab there is always at least one digit

```
for item in block:
     if "grab it" in item['text']:
            m = re.findall('grab \d+',item['text'])[0]
     print m
```

Comment: If the length of the item I am trying to grab varies and can be more than two characters so that saying `grab (..)` wouldn't always work... how could I accommodate that?

Comment: @nquestion my second one is match the string "grab xxx" x is digit and at least one, it will match "grab 23423" , "grab 9876" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This program will modify your `block` as you describe in your question:

```
from pprint import pprint
import re

block = [{'id':'10001', 'date':'2016-01-11', 'text':'this is some text. grab 40'},{'id':'10002', 'date':'2014-03-12', 'text':'this is some more text. grab 60'}]


pprint("Before:")
pprint(block)

for item in block:
    grab = re.search(r"grab\s+(\d+)", item['text'])
    if grab:
        item['grabbed'] = grab.groups()[0]

pprint("After:")
pprint(block)
```